# How to find table names which have a same value in other tables based aone column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database with many tables and that table has a common column. How can I retrieve that table which have same value in that column?

ex:-
I have 25 table, all tables have a column name `CCODE` now I want to know which tables have same value for this column?

Comment: Seems like you should consider re-designing your db.

Comment: i want query for only show result as i want.

Comment: Do you mean you want to (A) find all tables that also have that column name CCODE. Or, (B) do you want to search all CCODE columns (in different tables) for a specific value?

Comment: i  want to search all CCODE columns (in different tables) for a specific value

Comment: Then you'll have to do 25 different SELECT ... WHERE CCODE =

Comment: there is not a way that find with a single query?

Comment: No. (With a proper db design you rarely never run into problems like this...)

Comment: @jarlh Yes ;-) ... If you look at my answer you could set a variable to the result and add " ORDER BY CCode". Then execute it directly with EXEC and you have your "single query" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement will create an UNION SELECT what brings back all the data you need in one result set. Best is to set the query output to text and don't forget to set the query option max text to highest (8192). Take the result of this SELECT into a new SQL window and execute it:

```
    WITH AllTablesWithMyColumn AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME='CCODE'
    )
    SELECT STUFF(

(
    SELECT 'UNION SELECT ''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AS TableName, CCODE FROM ' + TABLE_NAME + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    FROM AllTablesWithMyColumn
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,6,'')
```

If you need any further help, just tell me...

Comment: SELECT 'birthday' AS TableName, CCODE FROM birthday  UNION SELECT 'leavmst' AS TableName, CCODE FROM leavmst  UNION SELECT 'STORE' AS TableName, CCODE FROM STORE  UNION SELECT 'tbl1' AS TableName, CCODE FROM tbl1  UNION SELECT 'tbl2' AS TableName, CCODE FROM tbl2

Comment: it gives this output not table name

Comment: You must paste this into a new query window and execute it. The result is a two-column table with the table name in one column an all CCode values beside...

Comment: yes it works...can u explain me the working of this query

Comment: @davidsam, The first "WITH" starts a CTE. It collects all table names which have a column called CCode. Look at "INFORMATION_SCHEMA". You can get a lot of meta data from there... The second part is tricky: I use a trick with XML to concatenate the UNION SELECT rows. The STUFF function takes away the first UNION. Please vote up and/or mark as helpful, thx